# In Ubuntu Karmic (Gnome 2.28), how do I enable both two-finger scrolling AND edge scrolling?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, scrolling

I use both of these frequently. In Jaunty (Gnome 2.26) I was able to use both, but the "mouse" dialog in Karmic makes me choose between the two. Is there any workaround for this?